# Facebook LikeBox not showing all the people that like a particular site

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-likebox

Here is a site that I'm upgrading for one of my clients:
http://home.minitraper.pl/

As you can see, rolling the mouse over the facebook icon on the right, the LikeBox panel shows only 2 faces/connections but there are 5 people who like the page. I was playing around with various versions of LikeBox code (the current one is the iframe version) but it didn't change a thing.

What can possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that these people have **set their FB preferences** so you cannot be seen here unless you are that person's friend. You can't do anything about this.

This seems the most likely answer.

Comment: Thanks, I tested it to see if you're right and it seems that it really works that way.